# Spell Check not working in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor.net

Spell Check is not working in my CKEditor. I tried `disableNativeSpellChecker = false` but in vain. Here is my config.js. My CKEditor version is 4.5.6 Any idea ?

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here.
// For complete reference see:
// http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = true;
// The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection'] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];

// Use line below for line break in toolbar
//      '/',

// Html encode ouput
config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;

config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,maximize,scayt';

// Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
// not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
config.removeButtons = 'Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Source,About,Styles,Blockquote,Link,Unlink,Anchor,Image,Table,HorizontalRule,SpecialChar';

// Set the most common block elements.
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

// Simplify the dialog windows.
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

Comment: If you hold down `CTRL` and right-click, you'll get the context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrated the Browser Spell check by adding the following code to config.js

```
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
config.removePlugins = 'liststyle,tabletools,scayt,menubutton,contextmenu';
```

Comment: Why have you removed so many plugins? I'm guessing that you need to remove only the contextmenu plugin?

Answer (score -1):

Hold down the SHIFT key then click the right mouse button on the text.

At this point the usual context menu with options will be displayed.

On Linux you can use either the SHIFT or the CONTROL keys.

On Mac you can use either the SHIFT or the COMMAND keys.

Here are screenshots WITH and WITHOUT modifier key.

[image: Without SHIFT key]

[image: With SHIFT key]